# Get Url Data Asp.Net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I want to do According to pull the query link id. How can I do. Anyone help me please.

sql.php returning table. You can see below. I want to do read step by step after that data I put into my gridview.

> [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

```
public static string ekle(string id)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string adres = "http://websitename.net/sql.php?id=" + id;
    WebRequest istek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);
    WebResponse cevap; 
    cevap = istek.GetResponse(); 
    StreamReader donenBilgiler = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream()); 
    string gelen = donenBilgiler.ReadToEnd(); //6
    int titleIndexBaslangici = gelen.IndexOf("<td colspan=4 class=\"yaziTracker\">") + 31;
    int titleIndexBitisi = gelen.Substring(titleIndexBaslangici).IndexOf("</td>"); 
    string baslik = gelen.Substring(titleIndexBaslangici, titleIndexBitisi);

    GridView g = new GridView();
    g.CssClass = "mGrid";
    g.ShowHeader = false;
    g.BorderWidth = 2;
    g.CellPadding = 15;
    g.CellSpacing = 15;
    g.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    g.DataSource = baslik;
    g.DataBind();

    return gelen;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking for. Do you just want to parse the HTML? If so, you could use an HTML parser like Html Agility Pack.

Comment: Yes I want to parse Html. Like this coming data with table. I want to do read step by step and put into my gridview. Completely I want to have my control this dataç

Comment: Yilmaz Alright. Then just use an HTML parser. HTML Agility Pack is probably the most widely used one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Do you understand me. I download htmlagilitypack. Now What can I do.

Comment: You gotta figure it out yourself. I don't know your HTML. Look up how to use the library and implement it. If you have problems, Google them. If you can't find the answer to your problem that way, then come back here and ask a specific question. No one's going to do your work for you.

Comment: I shared picture http://i.hizliresim.com/WEzz5m.png. I get result single line. How can I do.

Comment: Anyone help me. Please... ???